# Wifi with question mark only, it stopped working in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi

I using a thinkpad carbon 3th gen. Suddenly, after I disconnected a VPN, the wifi stopped working and there is a question mark in the top bar where the wifi icon is. I tried:

sudo service network-manager restart

It didn't work.

Comment: Try restarting the wifi all together in settings > wifi, this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same issue all night, and what seems to do this is connecting to multiple VPN/proxies. I just erased the system and installed it again.

Comment: and what happened next?